# ruby on rails create profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a controller profiles
now I have that code in my edit.html.erb and show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

so let's say when the user is updating the form the permalink will be:

```
profiles/:id/
```

but basically I want the permalink to be like that:

```
profiles/%username%
```

and I want it actually to be like a "my profile" controller, the user should edit just his profile, and the user should have only profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really easy to do. I assume you are using `resources` in your routes file. You only need to tell Rails that you would you like to use a slug instead of `id` to access, update, and delete a resources.

```
resources :profiles, param: :slug
```

Now, your resources will be generated through `slug`. And in your controller, in order to access a singe resources, you would do:

```
Profile.find_by_username(params[:slug])
```

Comment: Nice, this is really good example for seo urls such as like blogs... thx!

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that

Comment: @user4571629 If the answer worked for you, you can accept it.

Comment: ok, it wasn't clear that the username inside of the find_by_username should be the column form the db, and I didn't know what to write on the view too, something like that: <%= link_to 'My Profile', profile_path(slug: profile.name) %> so i guess it's working

Comment: Yes, you need to write `profile_path(slug: profile.name)`, as it would generate a link like `porfile/john`, not `profile/2`, assuming the name saved in the database for that profile is `john`, and id is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes it seem like you're coming from a wordpress background and don't fully have a handle on what Rails actually is, so if that's the case, you may want to do some more studying of the Rails Guides and find a few Rails tutorials to do. But, to answer your question, in your application_controller.rb, you could do something like this:

```
def profile_path(profile, options={})
  profile_url(profile, options.merge(:only_path => true))
end

def profile_url(profile, options={})
  url_for(options.merge(:controller => 'profiles', :action => 'show',
                      :id => profile.username))
end
```

Comment: It looks so complicated, can you lead me at least to tutorials?